# « Chez » ou « de » une liste?

Tags: traduction, prépositions, paroles-de-chanson

Référence : [Les paroles complètes de la chanson Mad Word, de Gary Jules](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/garyjules/madworld.html)

Le couplet original :

> *That dreams in which I'm dying*
>   *Are the best I've ever had*

Ma tentative de traduction :

> Les rêves dans lesquels je meurs
>   Sont les meilleurs de la liste

J'ai dû modifier les paroles pour la rime avec « triste »; la traduction propre serait « Les rêves dans lesquels je meurs sont les meilleurs **que j'ai eus.** »)

De toutes façons, est-il exact de dire « de » la liste ? Ou dois-je utiliser « chez » comme un « parmi » figuratif ?

Comment: Les meilleurs de la liste (ou sur la liste) mais on ne peut employer chez ici. Chez s'emploie pour des personnes (à la rigueur des animaux).

Comment: @Laure "sur la liste"... Chaque professeur de français m'a dit « n'employez *sur* et *dans* que dans le sens physique », et je continue à trouver des expressions qui ne le font pas.

Comment: Que veux-tu dire dans le sens  physique » ? Une liste c'est quelque chose de physique, non ? (Même si c'est une liste de rêves... ) Je suis certaine qu'on dit « sur la liste », je ne connais aucune règle contre, me trompé-je ? Dans ta phrase je pense que de est mieux de toutes façons.

Comment: @Laure ou pour une personne morale, dans le langage courant. "J'ai trouvé un pantalon chez [marque de supermarché]"

Comment: Amusant, je n'avais pas reconnu les paroles de la chanson. Comme elle est connue, je me suis permis d'ajouter quelques références

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Chez" dérive de "casa" (la maison en latin), et peut signifier initialement  "dans la maison de", selon une [étymologie anglo-saxonne](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=chez). Du côté d'Angoulême (un bonus à qui retrouve la chanson citée), on trouve des [lieux-dits](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lieu-dit#Appellatifs_.28topographiques.2C_floraux_ou_type_d.27habitat.29_et_noms_de_personnes) qui en gardent la trace, comme Chez-Billard-Haut.

[Le trésor de la langue française](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?11;s=4127796945;r=1;nat=;sol=0;) nous dit mieux :

> Préposition exprimant la relation « à l'intérieur de », cet intérieur
>   étant considéré comme le siège de phénomènes typiques.

En pratique, on est chez, on va chez un être, une personne physique (mon frère) ou morale (comme une marque de magasin), on mentionne une qualité dans une communauté stable, qui peut être inanimée (Lamartine) :

> Guetteur pâle, appliquant des verres grossissants ; Aux faits connus,
>   aux faits possibles, au bon sens ; Regardant le ciel spectre au fond du
>   télescope ; Chez les astres voyant, chez les hommes myope!

Donc, dans ce contexte, "chez" me semble impropre pour une liste.

Une suggestion conservant le nombre de pieds :

> Sont tout en haut de la liste

ou

> Sont au sommet de la liste

[AJOUT] : je suis très sensible aux paroles de chansons, et leur sens, comme l'indique le sujet [Help for non-native French speakers with song lyrics](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/610/help-for-non-native-french-speakers-with-song-lyrics/615#615).

Comment: "conservant le nombre de pieds"? Chacun n'a-t-il pas sept syllabes? API /sɔ̃ le mɛ.jœʁ də la list/; /sɔ̃‿tu‿tɑ̃‿no də la list/, /sɔ̃‿to sɔ.mɛ də la list/

Comment: Si, ils sonnent juste mieux à mon oreille